# Jomsocial not going to 2nd step when registering new user, it stays in 1st registration screen

Tags: redirect, registration, joomla2.5, jomsocial

Hope you all are doing great!

I just have installed jomsocial  Version: 2.6.2 and when I try to Register new user (jomsocial index, 1st step) and click next the page just reloads and nothing happens (I stay on 1st step and I’m not directed to the second step where personal info is entered). Everything works perfect in localhost but in my godaddy’s server I have this problem, any ideas? Help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure it's not a SEF urls issue (do the urls look the same on localhost and godaddy?),
then check the error logs.

Also see my answer to [JomSocial - Registration Redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480381/jomsocial-registration-redirection) it could be a solution for you too.

Comment: Thanks a lot Riccardo, definetively the problem was caused by the SEF urls, I made some changes to the default values in the Admin Panel and everything works great now, I really appreciate your response pal!